# There is a way to Sync a Google Sheet with a SQL or NoSQL Database?

Tags: mongodb, google-sheets, database

As im not a developper i often use Google Spreadsheets to prototype my projects.

Now I would like to connect a sheet to a database (like Mongo).
As my data can changes daily (i also use Zapier for automated actions) i assume it would be more easy to Sync my sheet with the database i use.

After a search on the Internet, i didnt find a solution.
Do you have any clue ?

Thanks, 
Seb.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You should be asking on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) instead.

Comment: hi Sebastien, did my answer helped you?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Yes it was exactly what i was looking for. Now I have to train myself to Firebase queries, Polymer 2.0 and Polyfire tools thats seems to work great with Firebase to exploit my data. Do you have resources or tutorials to advise me? :) Seb

Comment: man I like your attitude!, wish I had more time to invest on that field too, for resourses try to start with https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup and see where it leads you. this products are pretty awesome in documentation,, good luck with project and ping me if you develop something cool :)

Comment: @KresimirPendic - This is great. Is there a way to automate this using any built in apps script function like an onSave() method or something instead of the button? Thanks!

Comment: it can be pulled for sure @CoderX reach me over my profile if you need help or ask new question :)

Comment: Thanks @KresimirPendic, but the answer doesn't address the database from the original question (MongoDB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use free 1GB of firebase (cloud noSQL DB) for free, and if that's good enough for you then you can sync data from G Sheets->Firebase via custom Library,, more details here:

https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase

my video could help you maybe: https://youtu.be/9SIAnjgKZZQ